# Unable to add files to the publish profile

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-8, msdeploy

I'm trying to copy some additional files from a Modules to the IIS server.I've read and re-read [this post](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-extra-files) a lot of time as tried to follow answers on SS but I got no files copied.

Here's my pubxml

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
<WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
<LastUsedBuildConfiguration>XXX</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
<LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
<SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
<LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
<ExcludeApp_Data>True</ExcludeApp_Data>
<MSDeployServiceURL>http://XXX</MSDeployServiceURL>
<DeployIisAppPath>XXX</DeployIisAppPath>
<RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
<SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
<MSDeployPublishMethod>RemoteAgent</MSDeployPublishMethod>
<EnableMSDeployBackup>True</EnableMSDeployBackup>
<UserName>ifinformatica\administrator</UserName>
<_SavePWD>True</_SavePWD>
<PublishDatabaseSettings>
  <Objects xmlns="">
    <ObjectGroup Name="default" Order="1" Enabled="False">
      <Destination Path="" />
      <Object Type="DbDacFx">
        <PreSource Path="Data Source=XXX ;Initial Catalog=XXX ;User ID=XXX ;Password=XXX ;Application Name=XXX includeData="False" />
        <Source Path="$(IntermediateOutputPath)AutoScripts\default_IncrementalSchemaOnly.dacpac" dacpacAction="Deploy" />
      </Object>
      <UpdateFrom Type="Web.Config">
        <Source MatchValue="Data Source=XXX;Initial Catalog=XXX;User ID=XXX;Password=XXX;Application Name=XXX" MatchAttributes="$(UpdateFromConnectionStringAttributes)" />
      </UpdateFrom>
    </ObjectGroup>
  </Objects>
</PublishDatabaseSettings>
<ADUsesOwinOrOpenIdConnect>False</ADUsesOwinOrOpenIdConnect>
```

<_CustomFiles Include="..\Modules***" />
      
         %(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)    
      
    
  
  
    
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);

```
<CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
  CustomCollectFiles;
  $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
</CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
```

I'm using VS2015, and my Modules folder is correct (..\Modules)

[image]

Do you see any particular relevant error?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question all you need to is set the `Copy to Output Directory` property to `Always`.

[image]

To add files that are not part of your project you can [extend WebDeploy to include additional files via MSBuild](http://sedodream.com/2010/03/10/WebDeploymentToolIncludingOtherFiles.aspx) by adding them to the `CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn` property in VS2010.  [this property name changed for VS2012](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a00babf7-c8ee-46ad-be84-e5d77bd7190b/include-custom-files-webdeploy-vs-2012?forum=msbuild) to `CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn`.

Comment: this won't work in my case since the file put in the modules folder since the modules folder is filled at build time with the modules project I build then I copy .dll & .pdb files with post build action

Comment: That makes more sense.  Added another option to my answer that should help.